# Where can I find free images for game development?

Tags: image

I am developing a game. Writing a program is not too difficult for me. But I have a problem with drawing images. So my question is: where can I find free images for game development? Like characters walking towards directions, etc. Can somebody share some good websites where they have a ton of free images to download? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to just enter into your favorite search enginge `free game assets`? You might get even better results if you add what kind you are looking for (character sprite sheets, enemies, battle animations, models, etc)

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a crowd-sourced search engine. This website is not about giving you fish, it's about teaching you fishing.

Answer (score 1):

[Itch.io](https://itch.io/game-assets/free) has some great community-provided free assets. You can filter by 2D, pixel art, or whatever tags are appropriate for the assets you need.